# Importing class that require other imports

Tags: python, import

I have this structure:

```
myApp
  |---> module
  |      |---> __init__.py
  |      |---> constants.py
  |      |---> job.py
  |---> processor.py
```

job.py has a Job class that imports some constants in constants.py

```
import constants

class Job:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.status = constants.JOB_WAITING
    .
    .
    .
```

Then in my processor.py I'm trying to use the Job class.

```
from module1 import job

j = job.Job(123)
print(j.id)
```

I'm met with the exception "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'" from just the first line "from module1 import job"

A naive solution of adding "from module1 import constants" before that doesn't help. Nor would that be desirable because from the perspective of processor.py it just care about importing job and not worry about importing whatever else job needs.

Is the problem due to when I import job, it then looks for the import constants in the wrong path? Not sure how I fix it if that's the case.

Comment: Have you tried `from . import constants` inside of `job.py` instead of `import constants`? I suspect that when you load (via import) `job.py` it's trying to find a `constants.py` in the `myApp` folder rather than from the `module1` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in the same package, try

```
from . import constants
```